# What does this mean? "Notice: ob_flush() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to flush buffer zlib output compression"

Tags: php, buffer

I got this error after running the following function:

```
function send_buffer(){
  ob_end_flush(); 
  ob_flush(); 
  flush(); 
  ob_start();
}
```

The main body of my website takes a few seconds to load, so I want to send the header first. But I got the following error: `Notice: ob_flush() [ref.outcontrol]: failed to flush buffer zlib output compression`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use gzip/zlib compression as well as flush.

Pick one or the other. I'd recommend gzip rather than flush.

Comment: It is possible to use gzip/zlib with flush though and even ob_flush. It's tricky though. ob_flush needs tests for their being content to flush (if (ob_get_length()) {ob_flush();}) and you can't adjust the zlib.output_compression between the ob_start() and the ob_flush(). I'm using flush and ob_flush with two Apache configurations within these limitations.