# Laravel error: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0)

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

Every time I have an error, for example: trying to access a property of a non-object, I get this message:

> ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0)

open: `/home/admin/domains/mysite/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php`

```php
$previous = null;
$obStatus = ob_get_status(1);
while (($level = ob_get_level()) > 0 && $level !== $previous) {
    $previous = $level;
    if ($obStatus[$level - 1]) {
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', '>=')) {
            if (isset($obStatus[$level - 1]['flags']) && ($obStatus[$level - 1]['flags'] & PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE)) {
                ob_end_flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried setting in `php.ini`:

```php
zlib.output_compression = Off
zlib.output_handler =
```

but it does not help.

I am using `Laravel 4.1`

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Post your code that causing the error.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: In my case someone from the team added a statement in index.php that basically turned the output compression on. I just removed it and it was solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "Notice: ob\_flush() \[ref.outcontrol\]: failed to flush buffer zlib output compression"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353179/what-does-this-mean-notice-ob-flush-ref-outcontrol-failed-to-flush-buffe)

Answer (score 4):

If your are using @secction in your view then use @stop bellow the section to stop the section area

Comment: Nice but in my case it had nothing to do with that: check my comment here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915853/laravel-error-ob-end-flush-failed-to-send-buffer-of-zlib-output-compression/33200074#comment38393338_23915853

Comment: I simply add @endsection at the end of blade and my issue is resolved..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but I came across this question and thought I would share what fixed it for me, with the same error. It was caused by trying to set a null variable passed in via a section call. To fix it simply use a isset check.

```
@isset($var)
  @section('header', $var)
@endisset
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone, I received this error using laravel while creating a pdf. The solution was to add 2 data variables which were returned in the controller to the view-pdf.blade.php.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are missing an `@end` statement like `@endsection` in your blade file.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in production environment which is easy to fix if you are using Laravel any version of it. I solved this problem by editing the `env` file make sure you set `Production` instead of `local`

```
APP_ENV=Production
```

This what worked for me.